# How to handle volatile records efficiently

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have this problem and i wanted to run by others and to see if i can handle this in a better way.

We have 300 node cluster and we process transaction information/records on a daily basis. We could get ~ 10 million trasaction each day and the record size ~2K bytes each.

We currently use HDFS for data storage, pig and hive for data processing. We use the external hive table type in most cases where it is partitioned by transaction created date.

The business is such that we might get an update on a transaction that was created months or years before. Example, i might get an update of a transaction created 5 years back. We cant ignore this record but to reprocess the corresponding partition again just for a single record.

On a daily basis we end up processing 1000 partitions due to this. There are further ETL applications that uses these transaction table.

I understand that this is a limitation on hive/hdfs architecture.

I am sure that others would have had this problem, it will be really helpful if you can share the options that you might have tried and how did you over come this ?

Comment: does anyone have any thoughts here ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to overwrite partitions: you can simply insert into them. Do not include the "overwrite" in your insert commands.

Following is an example of a table partitioned by date, in which I did an insert (without ovewrite!) twice - and you can see the records are there . .twice!  So that shows the partition got appended, not overwritten/dropped.

insert into table insert_test **do not put overwrite here!**  select ..

```
hive> select * from insert_test;
OK
name    date
row1    2014-03-05
row2    2014-03-05
row1    2014-03-05
row2    2014-03-05
row3    2014-03-06
row4    2014-03-06
row3    2014-03-06
row4    2014-03-06
row5    2014-03-07
row5    2014-03-07
row6    2014-03-09
row7    2014-03-09
row6    2014-03-09
row7    2014-03-09
row8    2014-03-16
row8    2014-03-16
```